# How to prove distance from foci on an ellipse is equal to twice the semi-major axis (for specific ellipse)

Tags: conic-sections

Prove that for any point (x,y) on the conic, the sum of the distances to the two foci is always twice the semi-major axis.

I know that this can be proven in general for all ellipses but the practice question specifically asks for this to be proven for $\frac{x^2}{9}$ + $\frac{y^2}{4}$ = 1. I feel like I'm really close but I've managed to math myself into a corner somehow.

Let the foci ($\sqrt{5}$, 0) and (-$\sqrt{5}$, 0) be denoted as F and F'. Let the point on the conic be denoted P(x,y). We are required to show PF + PF' = 2a. In this case, since a = 3, 2a = 6.

PF = $\sqrt{(x-\sqrt{5})^2 + y^2}$ and PF' = $\sqrt{(x+\sqrt{5})^2 + y^2}$

By rearranging the equation for the ellipse, we get y$^2$ = 4 - $\frac{4}{9}$x$^2$.

Substitute this into PF and PF' to get:

PF = $\sqrt{(x-\sqrt{5})^2 + 4 - \frac{4}{9}x^2}$ = $\sqrt{\frac{5}{9}x^2 - 2\sqrt{5}x + 9}$ = $\sqrt{(x - \frac{9\sqrt{5}}{5})^2}$ = x - $\frac{9\sqrt{5}}{5}$

PF' = $\sqrt{(x+\sqrt{5})^2 + 4 - \frac{4}{9}x^2}$ = $\sqrt{\frac{5}{9}x^2 + 2\sqrt{5}x + 9}$ = $\sqrt{(x + \frac{9\sqrt{5}}{5})^2}$ = x + $\frac{9\sqrt{5}}{5}$

Therefore PF + PF' = 2x

And then I got stuck

Comment: Do you need a proof $PF+PF^\prime$ is constant? Because the cases where $P$ is at either end of the semi-major axis, which passes through both foci, provide an easy computation of the constant.

Comment: That would help for certain points but we are required to prove it for any point on the ellipse

Comment: Regarding your calculation  $\sqrt{\frac{5}{9}x^2 + 2\sqrt{5}x + 9}$ = $\sqrt{(x + \frac{9\sqrt{5}}{5})^2}$ are you sure?

Comment: @L.ABrudvik-Lindner So: yes, you do need a proof it's constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ellipse is a plane curve surrounding two foci, such that for all points on the curve, the sum of the two distances to the foci is a constant. One starts with $\sqrt{(x-c)^2+y^2}+\sqrt{(x+c)^2+y^2}=2a$ (your question) to arrive at $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$, where $2a$ is any constant (which ends up being the length of the semi-major axis), $b^2=a^2-c^2$, and the foci are $(-c,0),(+c,0)$. Note that $a,b,c\in\mathbb R^+$.

---

**Addendum**

Finding the distance of either foci from a point $P(x,y)$ on the ellipse, $$PF=\sqrt{(x-c)^2+y^2}=\sqrt{(x-c)^2+b^2-\frac{b^2}{a^2}x^2}=\sqrt{\frac{c^2}{a^2}x^2-2cx+a^2}=\left\lvert\frac ca x-a\right\rvert=a-ex$$
$$PF^\prime=\sqrt{(x+c)^2+y^2}=\sqrt{(x+c)^2+b^2-\frac{b^2}{a^2}x^2}=\sqrt{\frac{c^2}{a^2}x^2+2cx+a^2}=\left\lvert\frac ca x+a\right\rvert=a+ex$$
since $x\in[-a,+a]$, where $e=\frac ca$.

Comment: I'm not quite seeing how the top bit connects to the bottom bit

Comment: It's the exact answer I would've given. The distance of any point (x,y) from the foci is (a-ex, a+ex), a is length of semi major axis, e is the eccentricity of the ellipse. Bring your expression for distance in this form, and then it's simple addition. @L.ABrudvik-Lindner

Comment: Got it. Thank you

Comment: @L.ABrudvik-Lindner If you think you have got it, perhaps you can approve an answer.

Comment: Last question: How did you do the last step - to get a - ex. Because I keep getting ex - a (for PF). I'm assuming you use the quadratic formula

Comment: @L.ABrudvik-Lindner I have added a step $\sqrt{x^2}=\lvert x\rvert$.

Answer (score 0):

For such a question, the realm of complex numbers helps a lot.
In the complex plane, an ellipse is described by :
$$|z-a| + |z-b|=c$$
where z represents each point on the ellipse, (a,b) is a tuple of complex numbers (which may or may not be real), c is an arbitrary constant $\geq |a-b|$

Also note, (a,b) are the focii of the ellipse as well and c is the major axis.

Coming on to the question, just describe the given equation in the form of complex numbers, the result it direct.

---

So, the given ellipse is  $\frac{x^2}{9}$ + $\frac{y^2}{4}$ = 1 and
the focii ($\sqrt{5}$, 0) and (-$\sqrt{5}$, 0).

Describe this as
$$|z-\sqrt{5}| + |z-\sqrt{-5}|=6$$

This directly means that the sum of distance of any point $z$ on the ellipse is equal to the major axis.

Answer (score 0):

An ellipse is by definition the locus of the points such that the sum of their distances to the foci is constant.

From this property, the result is immediate:

$$PQ=FQ+QG.$$

[image]

Comment: No, it was because you didnt put a source where it originates from..or i mean how to see it intuitively. The image makes it a bit clear but before that it seemed like a comment (i mean no disrespect)

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi: no source is needed for the very well-known construction of the ellipse nor for the addition of segments, is it ?

Comment: Actually, i sympathize with the OP, considering the method adopted it is clear that one might have to be reminded such a thing ...the reminder would often include a proof or an insight from my side (and i have removed the dv as well)

Comment: A point F such that the ratio of distance between the point E and the directrix and the point E and point F is a fixed constant e which is $\leq$ 1

Comment: I hope you get my intentions as to why I said so...I just think the OP might not be familiar with the phrasing or the intuitions behind this specific definitions...be it trivial

Comment: am asking "An ellipse is by definition the locus of the points such that the sum of their distances to the foci is constant" ... how's one supposed to know this if the focus is defined to them using the eccentricity and directrix?

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi: my gardener knows.